# Why/how is org.json.JSONException unchecked?

Tags: java, json, eclipse, exception

Reading [How to identify checked and unchecked exceptions in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2418994/4486184) makes me wonder:

**Why is [org.json.JSONException](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONException.html) unchecked according to maven and eclipse?**
(no compilation error when not handled)

Both are extending java.lang.Exception according to [the javadoc](http://json-taglib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/atg/taglib/json/util/JSONException.html) and the [source code](http://sourceforge.net/p/json-taglib/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/main/java/atg/taglib/json/util/JSONException.java)...

---

org.JSON.JSONArray produces no error without try/catch:
[image: org.JSON.JSONArray produces no error without trycatch]

---

For comparison, here is a checked exception example:

atg.taglib.json.util.JSONArray produces an error without try/catch:
[image: atg.taglib.json.util.JSONArray produces an error without trycatch]

atg.taglib.json.util.JSONArray produces no error with try/catch:
[image: atg.taglib.json.util.JSONArray produces no error with trycatch]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have an old version of the `org.json` library. I guess they also haven't updated their doc in a while. Since [version 20131018](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20131018), `JSONException` extends `RuntimeException` and is therefore an unchecked exception.

You can see it in the source code, [here](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONException.java#L33).