# Why am i getting an error while instantiating within try with resources clause?

Tags: java, java-8, java-7

Here is the code which is giving the error -

```
try(StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter()) {
```

IDE is complaining as **Unhandled exception from auto-closeable resource:java.io.IOException** 
 Is it necessary to pass something in the constructor here ?

Comment: Missing the catch block?

Answer (score 8):

Because the `close` method (in `StringWriter`) is declared as:

```
public void close() throws IOException
```

And your try-with-resources will automatically call it.

Answer (score 3):

Add the catch block;

```
try(StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter()) {

      //Do something
} catch(IOException e){

      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the complaining msg suggest: you have an *Unhandled exception from auto-closeable resource:java.io.IOException* so your code is not completely written.

you need a catch:

```
try (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter()) {
    //Do something
} catch (IOException e) {
    //TODO
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, checked exceptions should be either declared (with throws clause) or handled (with catch, finally blocks) by the function in which those exceptions might be thrown. Your code does not do either, which is why you get a compiler error.

As an aside, see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418947/how-to-identify-checked-and-unchecked-exceptions-in-java).